# changing the URL in next j s is not working properly

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

i am currently working on next j s routing and i am passing multiple parameters in URL and i want hide those parameters and just want to show some text

i am passing parameters in router as

```
Router.push({path name:"/Home/about/"+id +"/"+name+"/"+age});
```

and i have tried to implement it as

```
router.push("/Home/about/" +id +"/" + name+ "/" +age, '/Home/about/'+name, { shallow: true })
```

but it not working and my page is

```
-Home
  -about
   -[...index].j s
  -index.j s
```

i am not getting where i am doing mistake,thanks in advance

Comment: `Router.push(`/Home/about/${id}/${name}/${age}`);` is what you should try. Check this: [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Sorry need to escape backticks:
`Router.push(\`/Home/about/${id}/${name}/${age}\`);`

Comment: @arturasmckwcz thanks,second one is working but how can i change the url

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking

Comment: i am getting dynamic routes,URL like /Home/about/1/username/22 instead of this i just want to show just like  /Home/about/username

Comment: Okay, and where are you going to show it?

Answer (score 0):

**step1**: create a folder inside pages a named it about then inside it a file [...slug].js

```
pages:
_app.js
index.js
about:
  [...slug].js
```

Try this:
Router.push(`/about/${id}/${name}/${age}`)

Comment: could tell me how to pass url like home/USA/about/1/name/23,when i am passing like this it is not taking USA as params,it's taking about as a param but about is my folder name

Comment: create a home folder inside pages then create a [...slug].js file inside the home folder. you can access all params.